# ReactiveStreamCrudRepository not returning data from postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, reactive-programming, micronaut

I'm new to reactive programming and micronaut. I'm basically working on simple CRUD APIs. I'm using Kotlin with micronaut. I'm not sure why the DB is not returning any Data and I'm stuck with this.

```
@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.POSTGRES)
interface EmployeeCrudRepository: ReactiveStreamsCrudRepository<EmployeeMaster, Int>, EmployeeRepository {
}
```

```
interface EmployeeRepository {
    fun findByEmployeeIdAndTcin(employeeId: UUID, tcin: String): Mono<EmployeeMaster>
}
```

```
@MappedEntity
@Table(name="employee")
data class EmployeeMaster (

    @Id
    @Column(name = "transaction_id")
    val transactionId: Int,

    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    val employeeId: UUID,

    @Column(name = "item_id")
    val itemId: UUID
)
```

```
fun getEmployeeDetailsResponse(registryId: UUID, itemId: String) : Mono<EmployeeDetailsDTO> {

        return getEmployeeDetails(employeeId, itemId)
            .map {
                    employeeDetails -> EmployeeDetailsDTO(employeeDetails)
            }
            .switchIfEmpty {
                logger.info("No records found")
                Mono.just(ItemDetailsDTO())
            }
    }
```

```
fun getEmployeeDetails(employeeId: UUID, itemId: String) : Mono<EmployeeDetailsDTO> {

        return employeeRepository.findByEmployeeIdAndTcin(registryId = registryId, tcin = itemId)
            .map {
                    employeeDetails -> EmployeeDetailsDTO(employeeDetails)
            }
            .switchIfEmpty {
                logger.info("No records found")
                Mono.just(EmployeeDetailsDTO())
            }
    }
```

I'm confused as to how to debug this to find the issue. The credentials all seem to be fine and the record I'm searching for exists in the DB.

```
flyway {
        // ./gradlew -Ppostgres_host=localhost -Ppostgres_ssl='' -Ppostgres_user=postgres -Ppostgres_pwd=postgres flywayMigrate -i
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://${postgres_host}:5432/postgres${postgres_ssl}"
        user = "${postgres_user}"
        password = "${postgres_pwd}"
        schemas = ['public']
    }
```

Issue Found:

My Bad, I was sending some other value and didn't realise that the value was incorrect. The implementation was fine and returning the response as expected. I'm writing kotlin and micronaut code for the first time and at the back of my head it always feels like the implementation was wrong.

Comment: Can you provide an example of usage `getEmployeeDetails`?

Comment: @ИванЗыков I've updated with usage of `getEmployeeDetails` in `getEmployeeDetailsResponse`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Access a Database with Micronaut Data R2DBC](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-data-r2dbc-repository-gradle-kotlin.html).

There are a number of things in your example that *look* wrong:

- `@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.POSTGRES)` should be `@R2dbcRepository`.
- `@Table` and `@Column` are JPA.

  - `@MappedEntity("employee")`
  - `@MappedProperty("item_id")`

You might not need `@MappedProperty("item_id")`, itemId should be mapped to item_id.